# How to divide two negative numbers using the two's complement method?

Tags: twos-complement

I was studying more about binary arithmetics and came across the problem `-21/-3`. The expected answer is `7`. Of course I know we can do it by canceling the negative sign and dividing `21` by `3`. I have seen the beauty of two's complement in the subtraction of two numbers.

So i started out like this:

```
-21 is: 11101011
-3  is: 11111101
```

Initially I tried out dividing but as numerator is greater than denominator division is not possible. Also it is clear that it is the equivalent of dividing `235` by `253`. So my question is how can I divide two negative numbers using two's complement method. Is this division allowed or isn't it possible to divide like this?

Comment: The beauty of two's complement lies in the fact that you can easily convert between positive and negative numbers. I don't think there is an easy solution to be able to divide two negative numbers, other than converting both to a positive integer (which is nothing more than `11111111 XOR 11111101` and `11111111 XOR 11101011`, then adding 1 to both).